# Question about SQL function GETDATE()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I insert time with that sql function and get the time out with a select time to present it.. it gives me time in an American way: 6/28/2009 instead of the European way that i want 28/06/2009. Is there a quick way to convert between the times.

And another question will i have a problem when i convert the time to DateTime instead of converting to other Time objects such as ... DateTimeOffset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) SQL function. Instead of `SELECT date FROM mytable;`, say `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, ...) AS mydate FROM mytable;`. You can configure the date formatting freely in analogy to `date(1)` on Linux.

The inverse function is [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: I dont use SQL to convert the date, but i use C# code when presenting the data.. can i use a  function to insert it as a European date...

Comment: Do you have an option to change your SQL query, though? Make the DB do the work so you don't have to.

Comment: lol..i thik i will use the DateTime class and extract the info and seperate it, I think it is they simplest option. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Convert function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)